# PI watch remote server for change/signal and execute locally

Tags: python, node.js

Need some help on where to start with this. Have a Pi3 and I want it to open a connection to a remote server (say node.js or whatever), and keep that connection open and constantly check for some kind of flag/value I set on the server itself.  I assume sockets are what I am looking for, but any tips or additional questions to help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the end aim?  I do not understand what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to take some action on the Pi whenever the flag changes on the remote server, you might want to look into using MQTT, a lightweight message queuing protocol that allows for you to easily have the Pi subscribe to messages that are produced by the remote server.

A very good MQTT implementation that should work on both ends is [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/).  It's very easy to set up and use for this type of continuous messaging.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having fun with one side being an http server hith LAMP (or close) and then have a python script on the rp making requests against the server using python-requests. Simple enough.